# How to display a web part list in blocks

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to create a web part in Sharepoint 2010 that matches the display layout of another web part that displays the list inside individual rectangles. But when I add the web part, all I can do is add link to a list. I tried to "Edit web part" but nothing in there seems to affect the display. Thoughts?
Thanks gang.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Under List Settings at the bottom is the view. Click or create a view and under Style you'll find a "boxed, No labels" option. That's it.